# Any reason why selenium webdriver test pass with launching browser

Tags: c#, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, specflow

I got this project from Github and for some reason I cannot figure out how the author of the project runs and passes tests without launching a browser window. Any help figuring this out will be much appreciated

https://github.com/executeautomation/SpecflowSeleniumParallel

Comment: Any specific parts you don't understand? Show us some examples from the project

Comment: @marcel the part I don’t understand is how the test gets run and pass without launching a browser. Did you compile the project and run it? I wonder if you experienced the same thing

Comment: Yes I did, I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: @marcel ok I look forward to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initialization method marked by the `BeforeScenario` attribute the method `SelectBrowser` is called with `BrowserType.Chrome`.

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void Initialize()
{
    SelectBrowser(BrowserType.Chrome);
}
```

This method is where the 'magic' happens, so let's take a look at it

```
internal void SelectBrowser(BrowserType browserType)
{
    switch (browserType)
    {
        case BrowserType.Chrome:
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.AddArgument("--headless");
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(_driver);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Notice the line saying `option.AddArgument("--headless");`. This will start the ChromeDriver running in headless mode, as a headless browser.

> A headless browser is a web browser without a graphical user interface. - Wikipedia

Since headless mode doesn't have a graphical user interface, you don't see the actual browser while running the tests.

If you remove the line `option.AddArgument("--headless");`, the ChromeDriver will open a window and you'll be able to see everything.